# Beamer - multimedia package - movie centering not working for frame larger than `width=\textwidth`

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, multimedia

I am trying to embed a movie in beamer using the multimedia packaged and I am having trouble centering it. I am setting the `width=1.1\textwidth` so the movie extends into the margins of the presentation. I have tried `\centering` and `\begin{center}` (see below) but when I do, the image and movie are offset to the right. It works fine if the image and movie width is equal or less than the `\textwidth`. Any advice is appreciated.

```
\begin{center}
\movie[width=1.1\textwidth,showcontrols=true]
        {\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{image.eps}}{movie.mp4} 
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`center(ing)` never places anything in the left margin, so this is independent of beamer and multimedia, use

```
\begin{center}\makebox[0pt]{\movie..}\end{center}
```

To hide the width.